# How to update a specific key in a specific section using sed?

Tags: sed, ini, ssh.net

I have an ini file similar to the following one:

```
[seciton1]
key1 = 0
key2 = 0
[section2]
key1 = 0
key2 = 0
```

I want to update key1 of section "section2" from 0 to 1. what will be the accurate sed command for the same.

also is sed command supported in SSH.NET c# library? if not then what are the ways using ssh.net we can update ini file.

Comment: Regexes are not suitable for this task, since they make it easy to destroy your file. You should use a proper ini-file-parser to manipulate the data.

Comment: What regexes did you try until now? Why / how don't they work?

Comment: The C# library simply takes care of connecting to a host. Whether or not that host has `sed` installed does not depend on how you SSH into it. But if it's even remotely Unix-like, it will have `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

This will update `key2` once when its after `section2`:

```
awk '/section2/ {f=1} /key2/ && f {$3=1;f=0} 1' file
[seciton1]
key1 = 0
key2 = 0
[section2]
key1 = 0
key2 = 1
```

To write it back to the original file, do:

```
awk '/section2/ {f=1} /key2/ && f {$3=1;f=0} 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^\[/h;G;/section2/s/\(key1 = \).*/\11/m;P;d' file
```

Make a copy of the section header and append it to each line. If the current section header is `section2` substitute `1` for the value of `key1`.

N.B. The `m` flag in the substitute command restricts the `.*` to the remainder of the first line (of the now two lines in the pattern space i.e. the current line and the appended section header) only.